# Temperature Conversion 2 byte

Tags: android, temperature, can-bus

I have difficulty in converting two bytes in temperature.
I have a control unit (temperature sensor) where I get the message of  temperature  with two bytes.

1 ) Example:

```
message: [ 40 ][ 25 ]
LSBYTE : [ 40 ]
MSBYTE : [ 25 ]
0.03125 C/bit
temperature: 25C° ( seen from the display of the control unit )
```

2 ) Example:

```
message: [ 40 ][ 26 ]
LSBYTE : [ 40 ]
MSBYTE : [ 26 ]
0.03125 C/bit
temperature: 30C° ( seen from the display of the control unit )
```

3 ) Example:

```
message: [ 20 ][ 26 ]
LSBYTE : [ 20 ]
MSBYTE : [ 26 ]
0.03125 C/bit
temperature: 32C° ( seen from the display of the control unit )
```

4 ) Example:

```
message: [ c0 ][ 25 ]
LSBYTE : [ c0 ]
MSBYTE : [ 26 ]
0.03125 C/bit
temperature: 29C° ( seen from the display of the control unit )
```

I do not know how to convert the message in temperature.

I ask for your support.
who can give me a solution, it can collaborate in my project ( create a app android to receive messages from the control unit )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is : if i have a example message: [20][26] and the temperature is 32C° 
the fomula is : 2620 in decimal is 9760 (9760 * 0.03125)-273.15= 31.85 = 32C°

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be giving you the whole temp in the upper byte, and the fraction in the lower byte. That would be 25.15625 (25 + 40/256).

I don't know where the 0.03125 C/bit comes from. That would mean 16bits = 0.5C. Seems like nonsense.

the other possible explanation is that .03125 * total = degrees C. If MSB is 25 and LSB is 40, the total is 201.25 degrees. so...probably not right.

EDIT:
0.03125 = 1/32

none of your points use the last 5 bits. that is fractional component. Take upper byte, lower byte, and shift right 5 bits then subtract 273 (for kelvin to C conversion).

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is not the right formula, because taking another message : '[40][26] temperature is 30 C°

Comment: A believe a datasheet for your module would be helpful here.

Comment: you data doesn't make sense. It isn't even linear. however, it is close to a kelvin amount if you take the full 2-byte number and multiply by 0.03125.

Comment: (MSBYTE*256 + LSBYTE)/32 - 273  <-- my numbers in decimal. Your numbers in hex.

Comment: the solution is :
if i have a example message: [20][26] and the temperature is 32C°
the fomula is : 2620 in decimal is 9760 
(9760 * 0.03125)-273.15= 31.85 = 32C°

Answer (score 0):

This is simply [Little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order. Your most important byte would be the MSB. It looks like it's natively in celsius. So simply read it like this (please excuse the pseudo-code):

```
var msbyte = read() // whatever you need to get the value
var lsbyte = read() // whatever you need to get the value

var temperature = msbyte
temperature += (lsbyte / 100)
```

In your case its simply 25.40C°

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is not the right formula, because taking another message : [40][26] temperature is 30 C°