# how to convert hex type value to temperature value in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an app in which i have to get the temperature data from the BLE. When i use characteristic.getvalue method then i am getting [B@6552d50  this type of value .I want to know that if it is temp value then how to convert it in no.

Comment: Hope this will help you. Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739937/temperature-conversion-2-byte

Comment: The value yo are getting back is an array of bytes, the documentation for the profile / device will tell you how to interpret the data.

Comment: if i am using characteristic.getproperties then i am getting 16 value what does that mean